# Who gets the elixir?

Tags: clash-royale

I want to know who gets the elixir from an enemy elixir golem in a 2v2 in Clash Royale. It seems like sometimes I get 3 of the 4 elixir, and my teammate gets 1, or I get no elixir and my teammate gets all 4. I’m just wondering what determines who gets elixir and how much they get?

Comment: Is it not just who kills the smallest blobs that actually give the elixer?

Comment: @n_plum I think so actually. Thanks

Comment: The elixir belongs to the player who by any means destroyed the lil golems - spells, troops, buildings, and crown towers

Comment: @hfanatic I appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depends on who kills the smallest blob.

You kill it = You get 1 elixir, your teammate kills it = they get 1 elixir.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).